# How to uninstall joomla component 2.5 manually

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I have looked this up in Google but none of the suggestions have paid off. I deleted files and folders and tables in database also, but no use.

How I can uninstall component properly in Joomla 2.5 so that I can reinstall without any errors

Moreover, I installed 3 times same component for errors. all times it was installed and showing 3 components with same name. I found it at backend "Extensions-> manage".

**These are the urls I tried..**

- http://www.phoca.cz/phocagallery/16-joomla/joomla/650-removing-component-from-joomla-system-manually
- http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2617632

**Errors are encountered during installation.**

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/content/50/11719350/html/cloud/administrator/components/com_payments

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/content/50/11719350/html/cloud/administrator/components/com_payments

JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/content/50/11719350/html/cloud/administrator/components/com_payments

JFolder: :files: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/content/50/11719350/html/cloud/administrator/components/com_payments

JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file

JFolder: :delete: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/content/50/11719350/html/cloud/administrator/components/com_payments

JFolder: :delete: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/content/50/11719350/html/cloud/components/com_payments

Component Uninstall: Can't uninstall. Please remove manually

Feel free to ask any doubts, still i'm ready to give you more information to get this fixed. thanks..

Comment: Please post the errors you are getting. Is it the same version you want to reinstall or a later version?

Comment: I think just go to the component folder and delete it, so in this case, /com_payments

Comment: component is of same version 2.5. I've already done with deleting of folders in components, languages at both site & admin.

Answer (score 3):

I'm back with positive result. i've fixed above problem pretty simple. i just placed respective folders and files of the component at corresponding places where all folders and files go after installation and tried to uninstall again, then it was worked fine, same way i uninstalled remaining 2 duplicate components as well.

Comment: Mark this as the answer so others know it is resolved.